# Scheduling Airflow DAG at two differents times per day

Tags: cron, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to launch a same DAG at 2 differents times in the same day **without copying this one**, for exemple I want to run it **every day** at 5:00 PM **and** 6:30 PM

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super certain if it will work but you might want to try passing a cron string to the schedule argument of the DAG. Where the cron defines your two times.

I'm also not certain you'll be able to have 5:00 and 6:30 only though, as different minute / hours.

This is a handy site for [validating cron expressions](https://crontab.guru/).

Answer (score 0):

This means running at hours 5 and 6 at minute 30.

A problem would be if you wanna 5:00 and  6:30, I don't guess CRON does not handle such options

[image]

Comment: even this can not be supported very well in airflow because cron in airflow is strict, "30 5,6 * * *" in my airflow (1.10.0) is actually scheduled at 21:30, 22:30 on every day.